# Why SettingWithCopyWarning is raised using .loc?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have checked similar questions on SO with the `SettingWithCopyWarning` error raised using `.loc` but I still don't understand why I have the error in the following example.

It appears line 3, I succeed to make it disappear with `.copy()` but I would like to understand why `.loc` didn't work specifically here.

Does making a conditional slice creates a view even if it's `.loc` ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame( data=[0,1,2,3,4,5], columns=['A'])
df.loc[:,'B'] = df.loc[:,'A'].values
dfa = df.loc[df.loc[:,'A'] < 4,:] # here .copy() removes the error
dfa.loc[:,'C'] = [3,2,1,0]
```

Edit : pandas version is `1.2.4`

Comment: as in the second line, you could use `dfa.loc[:,'C'] = pd.Series([3,2,1,0]).values` to avoid the warning - seems to be related to assigning a list.

Comment: I have still the warning doing that

Comment: ok I checked with pandas version 1.3.3 and 1.3.5, no warning with either of those. still weird...

Comment: so the third line, without the fourth, doesn't give you any error ?

Comment: with pandas 1.3.5, only the fourth line from your example raises SettingWithCopyWarning. If I replace it with `dfa.loc[:,'C'] = pd.Series([3,2,1,0]).values`, I don't get the warning. It also works with a named pd.Series (doesn't have to be a np.array).

Comment: Ok i'm stupid i thought he third line was the problem, you are right it's the fourth and must be linked to pandas version. Can you answer to the post, then i could give you the bounty ? Thanks !

Comment: Putting this here in comments to OP instead of on my answer.   After some cursory research, I think it has to do with the version of Pandas. It looks like older versions may return a view in both instances, value as a list or series. Whereas new versions of Pandas returns a view when the value is a list, but returns a copy when the value is a pd.series.

Comment: If I had a better answer than "it's version-related", I'd put it under the question, yes ^^ I still wonder *why* it is sometimes like that, and why pandas maintainers have chosen to change behaviour.

Comment: it seems to have a couple changes for `.loc` in the 1.3.0 releases notes, didnt get through all but should be there maybe https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html

Answer (score 1):

```
dfa = df.loc[df.loc[:,'A'] < 4,:]<br>
```

`dfa` is a slice of the df dataframe, still referencing the dataframe, a view.
.copy creates a separate copy, not just a view of the first dataframe.

```
dfa.loc[:,'C'] = [3,2,1,0]
```

When it's a view not a copy, you are getting the warning : A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.

.loc is locating the conditions you give it, but it's still a view that you're setting values to if you don't make it a copy of the dataframe.

Comment: so why does `dfa.loc[:,'C'] = pd.Series([3,2,1,0]).values` work for me without a warning (pandas 1.3.5)?

Comment: Not sure.  Using pandas 1.1.1 and I still get the error when using that.

Comment: since the OP is also using an older version (1.2.4), it seems to be version-specific

Comment: @GeorgeLPerkins but the point of `.loc` in the third line is to avoid chained indexing right ? so it avoids  it but still creates a view and it gives the error ? is it useless here then ?

Comment: It looks like older versions may return a view in both instances, value as a list or series.   Whereas new versions of Pandas returns a view when the value is a list, but returns a copy when the value is a pd.series.